# How to get the screen width in .Rprofile?

Tags: r

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-December/414547.html

The above post mentions `Sys.getenv('COLUMNS')`. But if I put it in .Rprofile, the result is just an empty string. Why COLUMNS is not available in this case?

How to get the screen width in .Rprofile in native R?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is specific to the operating system *and the display* used. I am on Linux and when I open R on the terminal (in fairly wide settings) I do get

```
> Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")
[1] "211"
>
```

but when I do it *on the same machine but in RStudio* I get

```
> Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")
[1] ""
>
```

(i.e. the empty value you report) because the RStudio console does not set it.  In Emacs/ESS we have a shortcut to query Emacs about what it knows and then set `options(width=...)` accordingly (which is handy).

You could probably dig it out of packages such as `vctrs` or `tibble` who 'always know' in order to limit the width of a `data.frame` (or alike) display.

Comment: I am on macOS, running R from the command line. I am currently using the external command `tput cols` to reliably get the width in .Rprofile.